# How to echo a href links with onclick alert php

Tags: php, html, css

### Problem

When i click this link its alert won't open what should I do ?

My Code

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onClick='alert('Not an Enumerator!')'>Location</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape quotes `\'` when necessary, try this:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onClick="alert(\'Not an Enumerator!\')">Location</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try By Following Example.

```html
<a href="#" onClick='alert("Not an Enumerator!")'>Location</a>
```

Don't Use Single quote inside alert

Answer (score 0):

Try below example you can do both alert and onclick or either based on return type of function called on click.

```
<?php
    echo "<td><a href='test.php' onclick='return test_click();'>Location</a></td>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function test_click(event){
        alert("Inside this function");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Expecting a better way to ask questions.